# In how many ways can two oranges, one apple, and one banana be distributed to two distinguishable bags?

Tags: combinatorics

I have $2$ oranges, $1$ apple and $1$ banana. I want to put $2$ of them at a time in $2$ bags, having $1$ ($1$ fruit at max in $1$ bag) each.

The $2$ oranges are indistinguishable (there are two but their value is same).
[order does matter for combination]

The bags have positions: like first bag will be at first position and second will be at second position, and it will not be changed.

> So please tell me in how many ways I can put them in bags?

yours sincerely

Comment: Are you asking in how many ways two of the four fruits can be distributed to two distinguishable bags so that one fruit is placed in each bag?

Answer (score 1):

Let O be an orange, A be an apple, B be a banana.

There are 3 ways to put fruit in a bag with an orange in the first bag: OO OA OB

There are 2 ways to put fruit in a bag with an apple in the first bag: AO AB

There are 2 ways to put fruit in a bag with a banana in the first bag: BO BA

There has to be either an orange, apple, or banana put in the first bag so these are all 7 ways to put fruit into the two bags.